# How to enter restricted characters in input field

Tags: jquery, html, validation, jtextfield

I am using jQuery method to block certain character in **input** field like `#$%^&*()`

Now,How do I input these character in input field (how to hack this input field).

```js
 $('#textinput').keypress(function (e) {
    var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9@]+$");
    var str = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
    if (regex.test(str)) {
        return true;
    }

    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="textinput" name="mname" type="text" placeholder="Sanoj Lawrence" class="form-control input-md">
```

Comment: Why do you *want* to put those characters in that input field? If they're blocked then they'll be blocked (I'd hope) on the server-side, blocking them client-side is merely a courtesy to save you redundant page-loads.

Comment: If you want to input these charter in input field copy and paste those character in input field which allow.

Comment: i need to check this method is secure or not will it restirct those charters or not

Comment: @Sadikhasan how do i block that even if user tries to copy and paste

Comment: You have to restrict `control` key

Comment: @Sadikhasan is there any method without control key

Comment: Right mouse click and copy paste

Comment: @Sadikhasan i need to block these letters even when user paste these letter in input field

Comment: @ohgodhelpme You asked the question "how to hack this input field". Actually your question should be "how can I prevent this input field from being hacked" ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `input` event, it triggers whenever the user changes the content of your input (typing, pasting via Ctrl + V, pasting via context menu etc.). Store the old value in a variable and reset the content whenever the user tries to enter an invalid value:

```
var textinput = $('#textinput');
var oldValue = textinput.val();
var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9@]*$");

textinput.bind('input', function () {
    if (regex.test(textinput.val())) {
        oldValue = textinput.val();
        return;
    }
    textinput.val(oldValue);
});
```

But as David Thomas pointed out in his comment to your question: The value must be checked on the server, too. Checking it via JavaScript is a nice feature for your users but will not help you if someone really wants to hack it. He could just disable JavaScript in his browser, or send the request using a faked form etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict mouse right click as follow and you need to code for restrict control key.

```
$("#textinput").on("contextmenu",function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

**Update**

```
$('#textinput').keypress(function (e) {
    var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9@]+$");
    var str = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);  
    if(e.ctrlKey)
    {
       return false;  //To restrict control key
    }
    if (regex.test(str)) {
        return true;
    }   
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```